# C# Object Model from XSD with Additional Property Attributes

Tags: c#, razor, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm using Microsoft's excellent XSD.exe tool to build a C# object model from my XSD schema.

I would like to add additional C# attributes to the resulting C# file auto-generated by XSD object model (to define Validation behavior for Razor but maybe for other things too).

For example, in my XSD I have something like the following:

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyThing">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SomeThings">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Email" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

The XSD tool will output a C# class with (amongst other things) a property such as this:

```cs
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Email {
            get {
                return this.emailField;
            }
            set {
                this.emailField = value;
            }
        }
```

I am wondering what might be the best way to add additional C# property attributes such as

```
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
```

So the final C# would be:

```cs
        /// <remarks/>
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Email {
            get {
                return this.emailField;
            }
            set {
                this.emailField = value;
            }
        }
```

Can this be done with the XSD.exe tool (I couldn't find a way)?  Or is there a way to add property attributes at runtime (is that a good idea)?

The ideal would be able to add this info the XSD, e.g.

```xml
<xs:attribute name="Email" someUnknownNamespace:customCSharpAttributes="Required,EmailAddress" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with the XSD.exe tool - ostensibly, it has no idea what an `EmailAddress` is, given that the field is given the type of `xs:string`.

However, you mention Razor and this makes me think of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. It has the given `[Required]` attribute and a lot more, including one that does email address annotations.

As far as automatically annotating the data - the XML schema you provided is insufficient to automatically be annotated with the tools in that namespace.

There are [open source solutions](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator) which do what you describe (given an adequate schema).

Comment: Yes, those example attributes are from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and  I was hoping to be able to add this info to the XSD for the tool to pick-up (example added to the question).  Thanks for the open source link, on first glance I cannot see a way to do that - but I will take a closer look.